# Basic probability exercise, picking components from box

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve this problem on probability:

Suppose a buyer of electrical components buys them in a box of $10$ units. Before buying the box, he inspects $3$ of them at random and accepts to buy the box if none of the three inspected components is damaged. Find the proportion of boxes he will buy if $30$ % of the boxes has $4$ damaged components and the other $70$% just $1$ damaged component.

So, I want to find the probability of the event $A=\{\text{buyer accepts the box}\}$, and since a random box has exactly 4 damaged units or 1 damaged unit, then, if for $i=1,4$ I call $A_i=\{\text{probability of a box having i damaged components}\}$ I can partition the sample space and apply conditional probability:$$P(A)=P(A|A_1)P(A_1)+P(A|A_4)P(A_4)$$$$=P(A|A_1)\dfrac{7}{10}+P(A|A_4)\dfrac{3}{10}$$

I am not sure how to calculate $P(A|A_i)$ for $i=1,4$, is there a common probability distribution that I can associate to this problem? I would appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, working on answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what you have here is a Bayesian statistic. Basically, a sequence of random events dependent on previous events. There are two pieces to this problem:

1. Probability of rejecting either box (on an individual basis)
2. Probability of rejecting a random box

Since the problem is ambiguous, I have chosen to handle both order-dependent testing. For order-independent, see@copper.hat's answer.

### Order-Dependent

Let's handle the probability of rejecting a single box first.

If we open a box with 4 bad ones and pull out three items at random, we need to compute the probability that all three pass in sequence.
$$P(pass_{4bad}) = {6 \over 10} *{5 \over 9}*{4 \over 8} = {120 \over 720} = {1 \over 6}$$
Now the probability of him rejecting the box is:
$$P(fail_{4bad})=1-P(pass_{4bad})={5\over 6}$$

For the box with only one failure, we repeat the process:
$$P(pass_{1bad})={9 \over 10}*{8 \over 9}*{7 \over 8}={504 \over 720} = {7\over 10}$$
So, the probability of rejection is:
$$P(fail_{1bad})=1-P(pass_{1bad})={3\over 10}$$

Now we can handle the second component of the calculation, which is the combination of the boxes. As you had written, the combined probability is the linear combination of the individual probabilities, weighted by the percentage of each type of box:
$$P(pass) = {7\over 10}P(pass_{1bad})+{3\over 10}P(pass_{4bad})={7\over 10}\cdot {7\over 10}+{3\over 10}\cdot{1 \over 6}$$
$$P(pass) = {49\over 100}+{3 \over 60} = {27\over 50} = \mathbf{54\%}$$
To get the probability of failure, we simply need to find the complement of this probability:
$$P(fail) = 1- P(pass) = {23\over 50}=\mathbf{46\%}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one thing: I think that in this problem we do not care about the order in which the buyer picks each component, so you are counting extra cases, but if the problem was taking into account the order in which the components are pulled out, then your solution is correct. I admit that the problem is a little ambiguous about this, it is not so clear to me if we care about the order or not. What do you think?

Comment: I get $46$%. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat, is it possible that you are computing probability of rejection, which would indeed be 46%. I may have answered the OP's question backwards, but it doesn't require much work to flip it around.

Comment: @user156441, you are correct, the problem is ambiguous. In actual QA testing, the process is usually to select the entire sample size, and run all tests simultaneously (thereby saving time, since cost is usually less of an issue). If, however, running the QA test is very expensive but quick, then running in sequence would be more likely.

Let me update my post with the solution for the order-independent case.

Comment: The question was to find the probability of rejection.

Comment: Good catch, updating post.

Comment: Don't! The question was changed.

Comment: Lol, no big deal, for reference, I'm just leaving both.

Answer (score 3):

The total number of ways you can choose $3$ objects from $10$ is $\binom{10}{3}$.

The total number of ways you can select $3$ objects from $10-k$ is $\binom{10-k}{3}$.

The answer:

> $p[A|A_k] = { \binom{10-k}{3} \over \binom{10}{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but aren't you calculating the probability of the complement event?, for example isn't $P(A|A_1)=\dfrac{\binom{10-1}{3}}{ \binom{10}{3}}$ instead of $1- \dfrac{\binom{10-1}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}$?

Comment: That is why you are getting $46$%.

Comment: The probability of rejecting is 1 minus the probability of accepting. The chance of accepting is given by the number of possibilities of choosing all passing components divided by the total number of possibilities.

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't know why I've copied rejecting, I had to calculate the probability of him buying, so your solution was correct, my mistake.

Comment: I have switched from reject to accept!

Comment: Ok, then I'll keep the problem that way (to buy/accept).